# Insert data into database after jQuery validation. Button only works for validation

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to insert the data into my database after jquery validation. However, the submit button only works for the validation and it won't submit data. Please help me thanks~

---

**This is my form**

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST">
<label for="username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="username" name="username">
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="name" name="name">
<label for="password">Password </label>
<input type="password" class="left" id="password" name="password">
<label for="repassword">Password </label>
<input type="password" class="left" id="repassword" name="repassword">
<label for="email">Email </label>
<input type="email" class="left" id="email" name="email">
<label for="contact">Contact</label>
<input type="text" class="contact" id="contact" name="contact">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />  
</form>
```

---

**This is my jquery validation form**

```
<script>
$.validator.addMethod('contact', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{3}-\d{7}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid phone number");

jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'passwordMatch', function(value, element) {

    // The two password inputs
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#repassword").val();

    // Check for equality with the password inputs
    if (password != confirmPassword ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Your Passwords Must Match");

$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
      debug:false,
      username: {
      required: true,
      rangelength:[4,10],
      // remote: "user_check2.php"
    },

    name: {
      required: true,
      rangelength:[4,10]
    },

    password: {
      required: true,
      rangelength:[6,10]
    },

    repassword: {
    passwordMatch: true // set this on the field you're trying to match
    },

    email: {
     required: true,
    },

    contact: {
     required: true,
    },
  },

   messages: {
    username: {
      //remote:"Username already existed",
      required:"Enter your username",
    },  

    name: {
      required:"Please enter your name",
    },

    password: {
      required:"Please enter your Password",
      rangelength:"You must contain 6 to 10 character"
    },

    contact: {
     required:"Please enter your phone number",
  },           
});
});

</script>
```

### **The last step is to insert the data into the table in database. However the submit button does not work.**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   

        $adminusername = $_POST["username"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $phone = $_POST["contact"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        //$query = "select * from admin where Admin_Username = '$adminusername'";
        //$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        //$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        mysqli_query($conn,"Insert into admin(Admin_Username,Admin_Name,Admin_Email,Admin_Contact,Admin_Password) values 
             ('$adminusername','$name','$email','$phone','$password')");
        mysqli_close($conn);    
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "the submit button does not work"? What happens?

Comment: The submit button only work for the error validation. When the validations are all correct, I cannot click on it nothing happen.

Comment: is there online sample? Just want to see console.log for any errors

Comment: Don't forget you need to do all your validation again, and perhaps some extra to check for SQL injection, on the server side in your PHP before inserting into db.

Comment: yes , i am new to jquery so i follow this http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/. Please help me solve it. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss `action` attribute in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="your_php_code.php">
```